# matrix multiplication error: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to convert the ra and dec coordinates of some matrix to galactic coordinates using matrix multiplication, but I got an error. Here the code:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from astropy.io import fits
    import astropy
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import math
    fits_filename="Gaia_DR2/gaiadr2_20pc.fits"
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    with fits.open(fits_filename) as data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data[1].data)
    df.columns = [c.lower() for c in df.columns]
    print("Columns:")
    print(df.columns.values)
    print("\n\n")
    print("Number of stars: ")
    nstars=len(df)
    print(nstars)
    ra=df['ra']
    dec=df['dec']
    df["ra_radians"]=np.radians(df.ra)
    df["dec_radians"]=np.radians(df.dec)
    df["cosra"] = [np.math.cos(df['ra_radians'])]
    df["cosdec"] = [np.math.cos(df['dec_radians'])]
    df["sinra"] = [np.math.sin(df['ra_radians'])]
    df["sindec"] = [np.math.sin(df['dec_radians'])]
    df["xICRS"]=np.multiply[df['cosra'],df['cosdec']]
    df["yICRS"]=np.multiply[df['sinra'], df['sindec']]
    df["zICRS"] = df["sindec"]
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: share data example you're using and point out what is the exact point in which you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is because functions like `np.math.cos` expect a float, not a series. They are not "vectorized". But instead of doing

```
df['cosra']= [np.math.cos(df['ra_radians'])]
df['xICRS']= np.multiply[df['cosra'],df['cosdec']]
```

you can do

```
df['cosra']= df['ra_radians'].map(np.math.cos)
df['xICRS']= df['cosra'] * df['cosdec']
```

Map applies the function (here `np.math.cos`) to each of the elements of the series and returns the series with the results.